# NuGet can't update packages

Tags: asp.net, webforms, nuget

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
>   2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

There are 3 packages I cannot update because of this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (Attempting to go from 1.1.2 to 2.0.0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features (Attempting to go from 1.1.2 to 2.0.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Primiatives (Attempting to go from 1.1.1 to 2.0.0)
```

Can I simply not use these packages if I'm on .net 4.7?

Comment: I suspect this will need an update to the NuGet client. By default NuGet allows [.NET Standard 2.0 to be used with .NET 4.6.3 projects](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/e9fa2e773917f7ce227f50da56bcdf5bdb206cba/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs#L373-L375). You may be able to workaround this by using the AssetsTargetFallback property in the .NET Framework project by setting it to allow .NETStandard 2.0.

Comment: Although it seems to work for me using a .NET 4.7 project using packages.config or PackageReference - this is in VS Mac.

Comment: @MattWard where do I used `AssetTargetFallback`?  And am I setting the value to `.NETStandard 2.0`?

Comment: You should be able to add it into the first PropertyGroup of your .NET project: `<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);netstandard20</AssetTargetFallback>`.

Comment: Sorry @MattWard I think I'm being an idiot as I'm not entirely sure what file/menu I should be looking in for this?

Comment: Sorry - you would need to edit the .csproj directly and add that in the first PropertyGroup.

Comment: @MattWard I get the error `The project file could not be loaded. The 'AssetTargetFallback' start tag on line 7 position 3 does not match the end tag of 'A'. Line 7, position 61.` when the .csproj file starts https://pastebin.com/Bq85Riwr

Comment: Edit: Scratch that, it works.  Some weird paste error

Comment: Still get the error:  `Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.`

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: @MattWard `Package Manager Console Host Version 4.0.0.2323` and in VS -> about it shows `Nuget Package Manager 4.0.0`

Comment: Hi Matt, updated VS and now they installed just fine :)  If you'd like to add an answer "Try updating VS to latest version" I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks for your help!